# Registering DLLs using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

as the title says I want to register some DLLs from my vb.net code,

- First of all, if you register a DLL and import the reference into your app, will someone else who will use the app need to register the DLL before they use the app.
- Second I want to check on startup if the DLL is not registered then register it then run the app (how do I do this, I have already imported the DLL in my resources so I pretty much want to access it from there or if there is a better way am open to suggestions).
- Third, from above its pretty much what I want to achieve, so if there is a better way of doing it, please am open to suggestion.

Comment: Please explain what is your concept of _register a DLL_ NET DLLs don't need to be _registered_, you just need to _reference_ them when you build your app.

Comment: It's a COM DLL which needs to be registered before being used @Steve

Comment: So you need to run REGSRV32 with a parameter using Process.Start method.

Comment: Registering COM components on-the-fly is no longer practical, UAC put a stop to that  You'll have one shot at getting the required permission from the user to alter the machine's configuration, you get it when he runs your Setup.exe installer.  If it has to be done by hand for some reason then it requires Regasm.exe, started from an elevated command prompt.  If you also maintain the client program then a reg-free manifest is an option, set the Isolated property to True on the type library reference.